# How to add background video stop button

Tags: jquery, css, html

I googled whole day but no result then I rerembered this website.

Can anyone tell me how to add stop button to background video?

html code:

```
<div id="background" class="background">
            <video id="video_background" src="video.mp4" autoplay>
        <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div><!--/ background-->
```

css code:

```
#video_background {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1000;
}
```

and website link: http://2gdmedia.com/dark

Comment: 2 seconds of Googling returned this: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_met_pause.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery - button or element that will stop the video has the attribute class='stopElementClass'

```
$(function(){
    $('.stopElementClass').on('click', function(){
        $('#video_background').get(0).pause();
    }
});
```

Check out
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement